# Is linear momentum times distance any meaningful quantity? $\vec{r} \cdot \vec{p}$ or $pr = mvr$ comparing to $\vec{r} \times \vec{p}$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, displacement

Angular momentum is$$ L=\vec{r} \times\vec{p}$$

I was wondering if the dot product has any meaning:
$$ ?= \vec{r} \cdot \vec{p}$$

Does it mean anything? It could also be rewritten like $ rp$ or $\Delta x p$. Other ways to write it is:

$$ \int p dx $$
$$ \vec{r} \cdot \vec{p}$$
$$pr = mvr$$

Is it useful in anyway? Or maybe in a certain construction, with centre of mass etc.

EDIT (15/5):
I found another way to find something relating these two quantities $p,x$ with the action:

$$\mathcal{S} =\int^{t_{1}}_{t_{0}}Ldt = \int^{t_{1}}_{t_{0}}\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^{2}dt  $$

$$\begin{split}
\mathcal{S} &=\int^{t_{1}}_{t_{0}}\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^{2}dt \\ &=\int^{x_{1}}_{x_{0}}\frac{1}{2}m(\frac{dx}{dt})^{2}\frac{dt}{dx}dx \\&=\int^{x_{1}}_{x_{0}}\frac{1}{2}mvdx \\&=\frac{1}{2}mv(x_{1}-x_{0}) \\&= \boxed{\frac{1}{2} p \Delta x}
\end{split}$$

Comment: A similar quantity plays a role in the derivation of the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem#Statement_and_derivation). In analytical mechanics you see products of positions and momenta (more specifically, generalized coordinates and generalized momenta) in several places, one being in the computation of [action-angle coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-angle_coordinates).

Comment: Your last derivation only holds if the particle's velocity is constant as it moves between the endpoints. That's true for a free particle, I suppose, but I suspect it doesn't hold in many other circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You could use it to derive the centripetal acceleration equation.

Suppose we have a particle moving around in a circle and a position vector to it from the center of the circle. Consider the quantity:

$$ Q = r \cdot p$$

$Q$ is equal to zero because $r$ and $p$ are perpendicular.

Differentiating both side:

$$ 0 = ( \frac{dr}{dt}) \cdot p + r \cdot \frac{dp}{dt}$$

We have,

$$ \frac{dr}{dt} = v$$ and,

$$ \frac{dp}{dt} = F$$

This leads us to:

$$ 0 = v \cdot p + r \cdot F$$

Now $p=mv$ and $ r \cdot F = |r| F_{centripetal}$:

$$ 0 =  m|v|^2 + |r| F_{centripetal}$$

Rearranging, we find:

$$ F_{centripetal} =  - \frac{m|v|^2}{r}$$

Comment: This is interesting thank you for this derivation. Is there a similar derivation for the Coriolis force?

Comment: I have done the calculation here in an inertial frame, the coriolis force appears in a non inertial frame, right? @bananenheld

Comment: But I mean the equivalent for the coriolis force in comparison to what the centripital force is to the centrifugal force.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not know if $\vec{r} \cdot \vec{p}$ has any physical significance; at least, I have never heard of it.

However, it is interesting to note that for $\theta= \frac{\pi}{4} + n\pi$, where $n \in\mathbb{Z}$, the dot product between position $\vec{r}$ and linear momentum $\vec{p}$ coincides with the *magnitude* of angular momentum:

$$\vec{r} \cdot \vec{p} = |\vec{r}||\vec{p}|\cos{(\pi/4)}=|\vec{r}||\vec{p}|\sin{(\pi/4)}=|\vec{r} \times \vec{p}|=|\vec{L}|$$

Comment: Yeah that is pretty interesting observation thank you. Could you think of an interesting effect or experiment that shows this coincidence of values?

Comment: I cannot think of a problem where the angle will be constantly $\theta= \frac{\pi}{4} + n\pi$, if that's what you are asking.  However, there are a lot of mechanics problems in which the angle will be *momentarily*  $\frac{\pi}{4} + n\pi$.  Such an example could be a bird flying, with you being the origin.